# Как правильно организовать запуск контейнера для получения результата его работы во внешнее окружение?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Приступил к изучению Докера и возникли сомнения в понимании каких-то фундаментальных проблем, которые не позволяют двигаться дальше. Например: на основании образа из репозитория создал контейнер, в котором находится всего 1 тест на Cypress. Вот Dockerfile:

```
   FROM cypress/base:14.17.0
   COPY . .
   RUN npm install --save-dev cypress
   RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify
   RUN $(npm bin)/cypress run
```

команда FROM cypress/base использует образ cypress/base из репозитория Cypress, а COPY копирует все из каталога из-под которого я стартую Докер, в корень создаваемого контейнера (надеюсь, что я это правильно понимаю). Потом устанавливается фрейморк Cypress, проверяется его установка и наконец запускается Cypress в котором уже существует тот самый тест. И все вроде бы хорошо, запускаю командой

`docker build -t cypress .`

тест отрабатывает, в окне командной строки появляются его результаты (которые, правда, почему-то не сохраняюся в окне командной строки, а куда-то пропадают). Но возникает вопрос: как запустить тест повторно? Если опять использовать эту же команду, то в окне командной строки выводится только информация о работе Докера, а вот результаты теста больше не появляются. Команда docker container ls -a говорит, что контейнеров нет. В идеале, ситуация должна быть такой: у меня есть тестовый проект, куда я постоянно добавляю новые тесты, сегодня один, завтра 121 и т.д. хотелось бы иметь возможность указанным выше образом эти тесты запускать сколько угодно раз. Скажите, пожалуйста, как этого можно добиться?

Answer (score 1):

Докер работает таким образом, что сначала вы собираете образ (можно себе его представить как компиляцию исполняемого файла из исходных файлов), а потом запускаете контейнер (или несколько) используя этот образ (это как запуск процесса используя исполняемый файл).

При этом, если исходные файлы не менялись, то не смысла заново пересобирать образ - он получится таким же. Поэтому если повторно запустить `docker build` не внося изменений, то докер использует закешированные образы и по сути ничего не делает.

Вам нужно либо перенести запуск тестов на этап собственно запуска. Или запускать дополнительно уже после сборки (даже если тесты запускались как часть шага `build`).

Запускать тесты во время сборки имеет смысл, если они не пройдут, то значит где-то есть ошибка в программе - и образ создавать нет смысла. Если вы хотите заново запустить тесты, то используйте команду `docker run`:

```
docker run -ti cypress xxx
```

Вместо `xxx` укажите команду, которую нужно запустить внутри контейнера. Я не знаком в `cypress` потому дальше предположение, что, вероятно, вам нужна команда `docker run -ti /bin/sh -c '$(npm bin)/cypress verify'`

Comment: Спасибо Вам, добрый человек :)